# Laravel Livewire wire:click creates infinite loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component that's a product filter. The queries all work fine, but sometimes it creates an infinite loop of requests.

You can see that happening in the GIF below which is a capture of the Laravel Debugbar. I'm clicking some filters and then suddenly it goes into this request loop.

[image]

I specifically use `wire:loading.attr="disabled"` on the filters in the view so someone can not select a filter while a request is still processing.

My code and some background:

**Livewire Component**

```php
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Brand;
use App\Models\Color;

class SearchProducts extends Component
{
    public ?array $brand = [];
    public ?array $color = [];

    protected $queryString = ['brand', 'color'];

    public function render()
    {
        $products = Product::query();

        $products = $products->with('brand');
        $products = $products->with('colors');

        $products = $this->filterBrands($products);
        $products = $this->filterColors($products);

        $products = $products->paginate(24);

        return view('livewire.search-products', [
            'all_brands' => Brand::where('status', 'active')->get(),
            'all_colors' => Color::where('status', 'active')->get(),
        ])->extends('app');
    }

    public function filterBrands($query)
    {
        $queryFilterBrand = array_filter($this->brand);
        
        return empty($queryFilterBrand) ? $query : $query->whereIn('brand_id', $queryFilterBrand);
    }

    public function filterColors($query)
    {
        $queryFilterColor = array_filter($this->color);

        return empty($queryFilterColor) ? $query : $query->whereHas('colors', function ($q) use ($queryFilterColor) {
            $q->whereIn('color_id', $queryFilterColor);
        });
    }

}
```

The reason that I use `array_filter` is because if I unselect a color value and use a character in the key (`wire:model="brand.b{{ $brand->id }}"`), instead of removing that from the array Livewire will set that key value to `false`. So then this `false` value will be put into the query which will give inaccurate results.

**Livewire views and the issue**

This works fine:

```
@foreach($all_brands as $brand)
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $brand->id }}" id="brand.{{ $brand->id }}" wire:model="brand.{{ $brand->id }}" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
    <label class="search-label search-wide-label mb-2" for="brand.{{ $brand->id }}">{{ $brand->title }} <i class="fal fa-times float-right selected-icon"></i></label>
@endforeach
```

But this creates an infinite loop when I select 2 or more colors after each other, or if I select 1 color and then deselect it. So it seems that issue occurs after the 2nd interaction:

```
@foreach($all_colors as $color)
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $color->id }}" id="color.{{ $color->id }}" wire:model="color.{{ $color->id }}" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
    <label class="search-label search-wide-label mb-2" for="color.{{ $color->id }}">{{ $color->title }} <i class="fal fa-times float-right selected-icon"></i></label>
@endforeach
```

This is weird because this blade snippet is exactly the same as for `$brands` as shown above:

The only thing that different is that the `colors` relationship is a `hasMany` vs a `belongsTo` for `brand`.

I'm now thinking that this is where the problem is...

**The things I've tried and didn't work**

- Remove the `@foreach` loop for `$all_colors` and just put the filters in plain HTML (to check if the issue is related to the loop)
- Adding `wire:key="brand.{{ $brand->id }}"` to the `input` element
- Adding `wire:key="brand.{{ $brand->id }}"` to a `div` around the `input` element
- Using `wire:model="brand.{{ $brand->id }}"` or `wire:model="brand.{{ $loop->id }}"` as was suggested in the comments (and what I thought solved the problem)
- Using `wire:model="brand.b{{ $brand->id }}"` so there's a unique key name
- Removing the `array_filter` approach (seems unlikely that this is the problem but just to test)
- Using buttons instead of checkboxes
- Using `defer`, `lazy` and/or `debounce`
- Paying an expert to try and fix it...

**Console error**

Last piece, I get this error in my console **only when the infinite loop happens** so it's very likely either a cause or effect.

`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'directive.value.split')`

`Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'directive.value.split')`

Both in `LoadingStates.js` which I think is a Livewire Javascript file.

The error there seems to be happening here:

```js
function startLoading(els) {
    els.forEach(({ el, directive }) => {
        if (directive.modifiers.includes('class')) {
            let classes = directive.value.split(' ').filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: You are using wire:model="brand" inside a loop, and whenever the checkbox input value changes this will trigger a  new ajax request to re-render the view, then the foreach loop will change the checkbox input value triggering another ajax and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I understand "the foreach loop will change the checkbox input value". Because of how Livewire works the checkbox with `wire:model="brand"` will keep that array in sync throughout requests?

Comment: I mean the "value" attribute of the checkbox, value="{{ $brand->id }}" this will change while looping and the model is listening for the change. I saw your answer and yes I think that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answered on GitHub issue, copied here for others to be able to find.

---

The problem is a morphdom issue.

The code that is triggering the errors and the loop is the wire:loading on your heading row and products row.

The reason is, when you select two or more colours, there are no results shown. What happens then is you're swapping from showing heading/products/total to showing an empty state.

But morphdom doesn't know by default that it should delete the old divs and add the new one. Instead it is trying to "morph" the old first div into the new one. That means that the wire:loading listeners are still registered when they shouldn't be. Hence why the error and the loop.

It's a simple fix though. You need to add wire keys to the divs defining what they are, so morphdom knows that they have actually changed completely, and to delete the old ones and add new ones.

Have a look at this screenshot below of the diff for what I did to get it working. I added a wire key for all the top level divs inside this file.

It's recommended whenever using conditionals like that to add wire:keys to any elements that are first level inside the conditional, so morphdom knows there has been a change. It's the same problem VueJS has, where keys are required inside loops.

[Screenshot of diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvkn7.png)

Comment: For the people reading this: I had another place in my Livewire component where there was a loop. What is described in this answer is adding a wire key outside of that loop so Livewire can keep track. In short: we were looking in the wrong place (as usual). Thanks Josh!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that if you're using `wire:model` in a `foreach` loop like this, you have to write it like this: `wire:model="brand.{{ $brand->id }}"`. Couldn't find it in the docs so hopefully it helps others here.

**Update**

The infinite loop is solved by this, but what's happening now is that the array values are set to zero instead of removed from the array once you select a checkbox and then click it again to unselect. So then the `whereIn` is going to look for brand IDs with value `0` which will not return results.

**Update 2**

The loop is actually not solved... See original question. Slapping a bounty on this $%$£# because too many hours and coffee were wasted.

Comment: Shouldn't be `brand.{{ $loop->index }}` ? At least, when you're using an array of data with `wire:model`, it expect to have the index. We can see this [here in the doc](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-models)

Comment: No because brands is an array in this case, not a model collection. It’s a bit confusing with all the brand variables and this array notation not being documented.

Comment: In the example a gave you, if you scroll a little bit, it uses `$index` of the loop with a collection of `Post`

Comment: Yes, but then the brands array values will be the loop count i stead of the brand ids that they should be. As you can see in the component the values of the array are passed to perform the query. So they need to be brand ids and not loop counts.

Answer (score 1):

A couple issues I see:

You're using the same wire:key for your `<div>` element and your `<input>` element. I would keep those unique.

Also, you're using the same `name` on the input element. This will cause issues with checkboxes as the value passed to the backend has the same name and I believe livewire will attempt to sync based on that. Changing the `name` field in your `input` to be unique is likely the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. I did however remove the `name` field altogether (as well as delete the `wire:key`) but not sure what combinations I did and did not try at this point so I'll test this properly.

Comment: No luck. I tried having using `wire:key` on the `div` only and remove the `name` field, and I tried removing  `wire:key` and using `name="brand.{{ brand->id }}"` but with both combination I still get the loop.

Comment: I've added a last update would be appreciated if you can have a look!

Comment: I've added a last update would be appreciated if you can have a look!

Comment: Is `$colors` set up the exact same as `$brands`? I noticed you changed `$all_brands` to `$brands`. Also, do you experience this issue when you don't have `wire:loading.attr="disabled"` on the input fields? Can you try without that?

Comment: Also, are there more livewire components downstream that could be compounding the issue? For example, how are you displaying the `$products` you've filtered? I haven't had much success replicating the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this. I've now updated the original question so it reflects the current code that I have. Apologies for all the changes but I've tried so many things that I'm a bit lost at the moment, but it now shows what the current state is.

Comment: I think you're correct that the `hasMany` relationship might be causing some issue as that's a more complex query but it should be a valid livewire datatype as it returns an Elloquent Collection. I'm trying to set something similar up on my end to see if I can replicate and drill down the issue.

Comment: @eskimo I've run into an issue using `wire:model="brand.{{ $brand->id }}"` which might also be affecting you. With `brand.{{ $brand->id }}`, livewire was storing it as an array - meaning it wasn't using the `$brand->id` as the key within my array. So if I dumped the array out, it would look like `{ [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(2) "13" [2]=> string(2) "14" }` where those string values are actually my `$brand->id`. Switching to a string identifier like `brand.brand{{ $brand->id }}` for my model yielded more consistent results: { ["brand12"]=> string(2) "12" ["brand13"]=> string(2) "13" }

Comment: @eskimo try upgrading to the latest livewire: 2.3.5 as it fixed some issue with arrays. I updated and the issue I described above has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks again. I was already on 2.3.5 with the issue. I've actually tried your approach earlier with `brand.b{{ $brand->id }}` but no luck as well. I'll keep working on this and post updates.

Comment: I know this is maybe a little unconventional but I'm happy to jump on a call and show you what is happening. Much easier than going back and forth here.